# Pass values between Views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have MainViewController calling WebViewController (From UICatalog sample application)
In WebViewController I make some function setValue(){...} to set some value passed as parameter to the variable (NSString *value) from WebViewController.h but when I try from MainViewController something like WebViewController targetViewController...
targetViewController.setValue(value), it says: "**error: request for member 'setValue' in something not s structure or union**"...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a property named "value", and use @sythesize to create a method for you, in which case you call using that "." notation:

```
targetViewController.value = whatever;
```

Or you can call the setter outright regardless of you or the @synthesize writing the method:

```
[targetViewController setValue:whatever];
```

The property syntax (class.property = whatever) is really just a shortcut of calling a "setValue:" method, and in return the @property and @synthesize mechanisms of properties are just writing a helpful bit of code for you.

Edit:  I had said before if you just wrote a "setValue:" method you could call it using the "class.value = newValue" notation, but that was incorrect - you have to define an @property to use "." notation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
targetViewController.value = whatever;
```

will only work if you already have the @property declared; if not, you'll need to use the full method calling syntax:

```
[targetViewController setValue: whatever];
```

Otherwise, Kendall is correct about using setters and @synthesize.

Also your syntax is written using procedural C

```
targetViewController.setValue(value);
```

which *definitely* won't work.

Comment: Whoops on my part, you are totally correct - after testing you have to use @property to call using the class.value syntax.  I'll edit my response so as not to spread false notions...

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be sure to #import your targetViewController.h file.